# How to fix "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" error in Excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Every time the cell A15 changes, I am trying to run 2 macros.

1. Unhide all rows, then
2. Hide all rows that have a zero value in column 82

I receive an error in my `Hide_Unused_Rows` macro along my `if` statement. I am unsure how to go about fixing this issue. I have tried changing it to equal "" and it still will not work. I am new to VBA and I am unsure how to fix the `If Cells (i, 82).Value = 0` condition.

Every once in a while it will run fine but the majority of the time I get this error.

Any advice?

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$15" Then
        Call UnHideRows
        Call Hide_Unused_Rows
    End If
End Sub

Sub UnHideRows()
Rows("20:258").Hidden = False
End Sub

Sub Hide_Unused_Rows()
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 20 To 257
        If Cells(i, 82).Value = 0 Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Completed"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Type mismatch

Comment: What is the value of `Cells(i, 83).Value` at the time of error? Are you running this in a debugger?

Comment: In the debugger, value = "Error 2015" and type= "Variant/Error." Also, Context lists: "Sheet1.Hide_Unused_Rows."

Comment: I updated my answer based on your reply

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to remark on your comment:**

You commented

> In the debugger, value = "Error 2015" and type= "Variant/Error"

This error means that your `Value` at run time is `#VALUE!`. You can handle this event properly by first using the following conditional:

```
 If Not IsError(Cells(i, 83).Value) Then
   ...
```